# facebook: what limits are there for inviting users to an event via graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am inviting users to an event via graph API.
We observed that there is a permission error thrown after 100 invitations for each event. Still I can't find anything about those limits in the API documentation.

Anyone knows whats going on here?

Comment: you ever figure this one out?

Comment: no. but i am still interested!

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit late. But here you go - http://www.facebook.com/help/202545109787461/